# Filter individuals that don't have data for the whole period

Tags: python, filter, rows

I am using Python 3.9 on Pycharm. I have the following dataframe:

```
  id  year  gdp
0  A  2019    3
1  A  2020    0
2  A  2021    5
3  B  2019    4
4  B  2020    2
5  B  2021    1
6  C  2020    5
7  C  2021    4
```

I want to keep individuals that have available data for the whole period. In other words, I would like to filter the rows such that I only keep id that have data for the three years `(2019, 2020, 2021)`. This means excluding all observations of id C and keep all observations of id A and B:

```
  id  year  gdp
0  A  2019    3
1  A  2020    0
2  A  2021    5
3  B  2019    4
4  B  2020    2
5  B  2021    1
```

Is it feasible in Python?

Answer (score 1):

As you want to include only the ids for which all three year exist, you can `group` the dataframe by `id` then `filter` based on set equalities for the years you want versus the years available for particular `id`:

```py
>>> years = {2019, 2020, 2021}
>>> df.groupby('id').filter(lambda x: set(x['year'].values)==years)
    # df is your dataframe

  id  year  gdp
0  A  2019    3
1  A  2020    0
2  A  2021    5
3  B  2019    4
4  B  2020    2
5  B  2021    1
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make a set of all the years existing in the column `year` then use a boolean mask to filter your dataframe. For that, you need [**`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [**`pandas.DataFrame.transform`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) to count the occurences of each `id` in each group of `year`.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

s = """id   year    gdp
A   2019    3
A   2020    0
A   2021    5
B   2019    4
B   2020    2
B   2021    1
C   2020    5
C   2021    4
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep='\t')
    
mask = df.groupby('id')['year'].transform('count').eq(len(set(df['id'])))

out = df[mask]
```

##### `>>> print(out)`

```
  id  year  gdp
0  A  2019    3
1  A  2020    0
2  A  2021    5
3  B  2019    4
4  B  2020    2
5  B  2021    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) to automatically find ids with missing values:

```
keep = df.pivot('id', 'year', 'gdp').dropna().index
# ['A', 'B']

out = df[df['id'].isin(keep)]
```

output:

```
  id  year  gdp
0  A  2019    3
1  A  2020    0
2  A  2021    5
3  B  2019    4
4  B  2020    2
5  B  2021    1
```